# How to enable SSO login to Jira Service Desk?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am impressed with JIRA Service Desk. I have hundreds of users and I have added all those user's email addresses into the application. We already have an employee portal where they can log timesheets, request leaves and all and we planned to use JIRA Service Desk for all kind of IT service requests.

The problem now is multiple log in. Every user will log into employee portal and also to JIRA to raise requests. They feel irritated to log in multiple times.

Is there any option (API) to enable SSO login to JIRA?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can connect JIRA to Active Directory or to another LDAP service. See https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/connecting-to-an-ldap-directory-802592350.html for detailed instructions.